# json - create json object id based upon variable

Tags: javascript, json

Is there a way to create a JSON object ID with a variable?

```
var json_result = [];
var id = 20;
json_result.push({id: {parentId: parentId, position: position}});
```

This results into a json object with the value 'id' as the id. I want to achieve to have the value '20' as the key.

EDIT: Include solution:

```
var json_result = {};
var id = 20;
json_result[id] = {parentId: parentId, position: position};
```

Now you can access parentId and position like this:

```
json_result[20].position
json_result[20].parentId
```

Comment: That's a *JavaScript object*, not a JSON object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot write such an object literal (it's not a "JSON object" by the way; just a plain Javascript object), but you can do it like this:

```
var o = {};
o[id] = {parentId: parentId, position: position};
json_result.push(o);
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But I thought I should be able to access the value then like this: console.log(json_result[20]); But it does not work. Any idea what I have to change? Basically I want to access the parentid and position of the id 20 without looping over the entire array.

Comment: @TomTom: When you are pushing `o` into `json_result` you are not giving it a key equal to `id`. If you want to do that, simply use `o` as your `json_result` and remove all references to the original `json_result` (which is an array; you don't want that, based on the comment).

Comment: Thanks, now I got it. Included the solution in my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
var json_result = [];
var id = 20;
var obj = {};
obj[id] = "something";
json_result.push(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the reasons the JSON spec says that keys should be strings.  Your JSON should really look like this:

```
{
  "20": {
    "parentId": ..., 
    "position": ...}
}
```

... or similar.  Check out http://json.org/example.html

Comment: He's trying to figure out how to get the `20` to be the key.  Also, the OP really meant *JavaScript object*, not JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
var obj = {};
obj[id] = {parentId: parentId, position: position};
json_result.push(obj);
```